# How common is Geordi's VISOR technology?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, technology

As far as I recall, various people were not familiar with the [VISOR](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/VISOR) when they first encounter Geordi.  Yet he was apparently fitted with it when he was five.

Is the VISOR extremely rare or unique?   Is it experimental?   Did we ever encounter another instance of similar technology?

Comment: Memory Beta cites a book that indicates use of the VISOR is rare due to pain. Later, (due to the events of "Generations") the VISOR is considered a Starfleet security risk and Geordi is required to move to lower rank and security authorization or have it replaced with implants - http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/VISOR

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on Geordi's conversations with Doctors Crusher and Pulaski in [TNG: Encounter at Farpoint, Part I](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/101.htm) and [TNG: Loud As A Whisper](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/132.htm) it would seem that the use of this technology is **vanishingly rare**. Sufficiently so that a [Starfleet doctor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Beverly_Crusher) with two decades of medical experience hasn't even *seen* one in real life and a renowned [specialist in surgical research](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Katherine_Pulaski) has only encountered a few similar cases in all of her years of practice.

> **CRUSHER:** ***Naturally I've heard of your case.** The visor implants you wear ...*
>
> **LAFORGE:** *Is a remarkable piece of bio-electronic engineering by which I quote see much of the EM spectrum ranging from simple heat and
> infrared through radio waves et cetera, et cetera, and forgive me if
> I've said and listened to this a thousand times before.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Encounter at Farpoint](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/101.htm)</sup></sub>

and

> **PULASKI:** *It's possible to install optical devices which look like normal eyes, and would still give you about the same visual range as
> the visor.*
>
> **LAFORGE:** *Done? You say almost. How much reduction?*
>
> **PULASKI:** *Twenty percent. There is another option. I can attempt to regenerate your optic nerve, and, with the help of the replicator,
> fashion normal eyes. You would see like everyone else.*
>
> **LAFORGE:** *Wait a minute. I was told that was impossible.*
>
> **PULASKI:** ***I've done it twice, in situations somewhat similar to yours.** Geordi, it would eliminate the constant pain you are under. Why
> are you hesitating?*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Loud as a Whisper](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/132.htm)</sup></sub>

---

That all being said, we see other Starfleet personnel wearing VISORs in 2380, in *LD: Room for Growth* and *LD: Second Contact*. It's possible that Geordi made them fashionable given how [famous the Enterprise crew are](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/are-the-crew-of-the-enterprise-d-famous).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, to play devil's advocate, it's not inconceivable that it's only vanishingly rare for Starfleet personnel.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Actually that's not a bad point. How many blind people do you find working as pilots for American Airlines?

Comment: "Oh, landed a plane on the river. Such a great pilot. You know what a great pilot would have done? Not hit the birds. I don't hit birds every day" - Carol, 30 Rock

Comment: alternatively it might simply be rare beacuse many forms of blindness can be cured without the aid of implants in the twenty-fourth century?